# Error : 80040154 Class not registered , in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, plesk

I have a page that get template file of office and get all ContentControl  of it.

I use this code.

```
Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Object oTrue = true;
Object oFalse = false;
var oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var oWordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/DietTemplate")))
Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/DietTemplate"));
Request.Files[0].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/DietTemplate/" +  Request.Files[0].FileName));
Object oTemplatePath = Server.MapPath("~/DietTemplate/" + Request.Files[0].FileName);
oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
var fields = new List<DietFields>();
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl content in oWordDoc.ContentControls)
  {
     if (content.Title != null)
       {
         var field = new DietFields();
         field.Name = content.Title;
         field.DefaultValue = (content.Range.Text != "Click here to enter text.") ? content.Range.Text : string.Empty;
         fields.Add(field);
       }
  }
model.Fields = fields;
_db.Diets.Add(model);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

It is work on local, But when i upload this in host(plesk), i get error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I contact to host support and install office on it. but get error again.

Comment: using word files with web applications isn't a good idea, i used it before and had tons of problems related to security and configuring components to enable iis to access word files, the thing that would be harder in your case as you are using plesk - i used a local server - so i recommend to look for an alternate, you could generate html document or use any report service instead

Comment: I have a template file and want to save it, In your opinion, what alternative do I use.

Comment: may be google document, check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407640/google-api-to-get-the-content-of-document-speadsheet). it could be useful

Comment: Checkout OpenXML. There are opensource libraries avaliable  based on openxml.